# Content Wont Scroll With Footer And Header Fixed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have set both the header and the footer to fixed but still cannot get the content to adjust in IPhone.

[image]

Here is my layout code

```
<body>  
    <div data-role="page"  @(Page.Id == null ? string.Empty : "id=" + Page.Id) data-fullscreen="false">
     @*    @RenderSection("MoreCode", false)*@


      @if (IsSectionDefined("Header"))
      { 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">


         @RenderSection("Header", false)


        </div><!-- /header -->
      }


     <div data-role="content">  
         @RenderBody()        

     </div><!-- /content -->


       <div data-role="footer" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">

   <div class="center-wrapper">
        <table border="0">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="basic">
        Place Of Interest
        </label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="0">
        <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="@Url.Action("TermsOfUse", "Home")" data-mini="true">Terms of Use</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <label for="basic">
        |
        </label>
        </td>
         <td>
          <a href="@Url.Action("PrivacyPolicy", "Home")" data-mini="true">Privacy Policy</a>
        </td>
        </tr>     
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>    
        </table>      
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is my View

```
<h3 style='color:#4FA600; font-weight:bold;'>@ViewBag.Number</h3>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign=middle style=' font-weight:bold; color:#FFFFFF; background:#4FA600; '>
<label for="basic">Available Documents</label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="middle" style=' font-weight:bold;'>
Type
</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" style=' font-weight:bold;'>
Description
</td>

</tr>
@{
    foreach(var row in Model)
    {       

        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
        @row.DocType
        </td>

        <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"  class="my-btn">@row.Description</a>
        </td>
        </tr>


    }

    }  
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Isnt jquerymobile suppose to manually adjust? It renders fine in firefox. What can I do to make the content fully display?

Comment: Which version of iOS? pre 4.2 iOS didn't support inline scrolling...

Comment: Im using OS 5.1.1, why isnt the content fitting in the space provided? If it doesnt fit why cant I scroll too it? The footer should be fixed as I set it in the markup

Comment: Just ran through your code... and my first suspect would be the use of `<table>`s

Comment: I cant use tables? How can I make the ui look like this without the use of tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\The issue was I had this in my css:

```
[data-role=page]{height: 100% !important; position:relative !important;}
```

I got this code from use theme roller not sure why this messed it up. Maybe someone can clarify would be appreciated